# Collision detection using QuadTree in AS3

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, collision-detection, flashdevelop

Ok. I managed to make and use QuadTree for my collision Detection alghorithm and it works just fine. I have my enemies and put them in the QuadTree, than retrieve the candidates that could possibly collide with my hero. That is hitTestObject() many agains one.

The problem I reached is how to test fastly whether some of the enmies collide with my hero's bullets. Roughly I have 4-6 bullets on the stage at same time. In this case I have hitTstObject 4-6 bullets against many enemy objects, which in turns gives me for cycle in for cycle so even using quad tree after a while things start to lag on the stage :)

I used this tutorial [quadtree in java](http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementation/quick-tip-use-quadtrees-to-detect-likely-collisions-in-2d-space/) to develop m alghorithm but it works fine only in the above case. What should I do in this circumstance? Use another algorithm for many agains many or ?

Roughly this is the code

```
 bulletsQuadTree.clear();
 for (var bIndex:uint; bIndex < allEnemies.length; bIndex += 1 )        
 {
  bulletsQuadTree.insert(allEnemies[bIndex]);
 }

for (var bc:uint = 0; bc < bullets.length; bc += 1 )
{
    var enemiesCollideBullets:Array = new Array();
    bulletsQuadTree.retrieve(enemiesCollideBullets, bullets[bc]);

    for (var dc:uint = 0; dc < enemiesCollideBullets.length; dc += 1 )
    {
        if (enemiesCollideBullets[dc].hitTestObject(bullets[bc]))
        {
            enemiesCollideBullets[dc].destroy();
            enemiesCollideBullets.splice(dc, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

So this happens on each frame which are many operations per frame :(

Each bullet is treated as a hero and an array of enemies is returned for each bullet that could possibly collide with.

Comment: I'd rather use PixelPerfectCollisionDetection.

Comment: Is it possible that the real issue is that you're using Flex (which is constantly invalidating a bunch of stuff under the hood, plus all the data binding overhead, etc.)? This is probably something you should do in Flash. Beyond that, there's no way to debug your code from what you've posted.

Comment: No debugging needed. The problem lies in for in for cycle. too much operations per frame. So basically I think Abe gave the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to improve the performance of this loop, change this line:

```
enemiesCollideBullets[dc].hitTestObject(bullets[bc]);
```

The actionscript hit test functions are slow. A much better approach for bullets is to check for the distance.

```
var distanceSquared:number = (bullet.width/2 + object.width/2) * (bullet.width/2 + object.width/2);
if((bullet.x - object.x)* (bullet.x - object.x) + (bullet.y - object.y)* (bullet.y - object.y) < distanceSquared) {
// its a hit!
```

Comment: Is this faster than using Point.distance?.